# Проблема с js в браузере

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Всем привет, пытаюсь отсортировать рандомно созданный массив с координатами. Сортирую просто - сравниваю первые координаты. Написал для теста всё на [repl.it](https://repl.it/@DimonDighidon/CheapVariableNewsaggregator). Там всё прекрасно работает. Как только я копирую ТОЧНО ТАКОЙ ЖЕ код в html документ мне выдаёт два не отсортированный массива. Я просто в замешательстве. Помогите советом, а то у меня уже начинается паническая атака...

На repl.it
[image: На repl.it]

Вставил в html
[image: Вставил в html]

Вывод в браузере
[image: Вывод в браузере]

Comment: Странно, что у вас оно работает хоть как-то, ведь `compareNumeric` никогда не возвращает число меньшее нуля, а это вопиюще некорректное поведение

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с andreymal, тоже теперь не понимаю как ОНО работало. Но когда я заменил return 0 на return -1 в браузере все заработало.

Comment: Вам нужно возвращать 0 в случае равенства. Иначе равные элементы будут пересортировываться. Почитайте про устойчивость сортировки. Вообще говоря, на устойчивость влияет алгоритм, но в случае, если сравнение равных ключей будет возвращать -1 - любой алгоритм будет неустойчивым.